# TypeScript Typings with Blazor

Tags: typescript, blazor

I have typescript compiling `*.ts` files in my Blazor (.NET 5) project. In my Aurelia version I use a Typescript declaration file (`index.d.ts`) and it is referenced in `package.json` under `devDependencies/@types/....`

How do I use the Typings files with Blazor in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019?

I'm using `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild` to compile my TypeScript. I just need TypeScript editor/compiler to recognize the types of my external JavaScrip module.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I had to do was place the `.d.ts` file in the same folder as my `.ts` that needed it and TypeScript sees it from within Microsoft Visual Studio 2019.